# Overriding setAttribute and getAttribute functions multiple times (in different traits)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column storing credit card numbers. For now, it's values are being `encrypted` before writing to database and `decrypted` on reading from table.

What I want to do is to 'mask the value' once it is read from table and `decrypted`. By 'masking the value' I mean replacing everything but last for digits with an `x`. For example `4242 4242 4242 4242` should become `x4242`. For this purpose I have created new `trait`, calling it `Maskable` where function `getAttribute` is overriden to do above mentioned, and also `setAttribute` function is overriden to check if value which is trying to be saved equals to 'x' + four digits. If yes, just skip this column, because that means it hasn't been changed. Otherwise save it normally, and change the value in table (but encrypt it first).

Is it possible to override same function in one model multiple times? If yes, how could I tell which `set/getAttribute` method should come first? I am using `Encryptable trait` in different models, but the new `trait` would be used only here for now and that's why I can't do this all inside same `trait`.

**EDIT**

Error I am facing: 
`Trait method getAttribute has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on ...`

```
//My example model

class RentalApplication extends Model {
use Encryptable, Maskable;

protected $encryptable = ['card_number'];
protected $maskable = ['card_number'];
}

//Traits

trait Maskable {

public function getAttribute($key) {
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    if(isset($this->maskable) && in_array($key, $this->maskable) && !empty($value)) {
        try {
            $value = 'x'.substr($value, -4);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

trait Encryptable {

public function getAttribute($key) {
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    if(isset($this->encryptable) && in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && !empty($value)) {
        try {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
    if(isset($this->encryptable) && in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && !is_null($value)) {
        if(Schema::hasColumn($this->getTable(), $key.'_search') && !empty($this->id)) {
            parent::setAttribute($key.'_search', hash('sha512', env('APP_KEY').$this->id.$value));
        }
        $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }
    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}

public function toArray() {
    $array = parent::toArray();
    foreach($this->encryptable as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            $array[$key] = $this->{$key};
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
}
```

Comment: you want to call `getAttribute` one after the other or override it completely for a specific model ?

Comment: I am not sure I can see the difference, but I shouldn't ever use model's `set/getAttribute` functions. Instead I should always use the ones from `Encryptable` trait. The new ones from `Maskable` trait should be used as addition to these, after the value is `decrypted` and before it's `encrypted`.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do. can you provide some code/errors you're encountering? for what i understood, here is a hint: you can't override the same function in two traits on the same class, you will need to do a `Conflict Resolution` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict

Comment: Okay, let me check this article

Comment: Why not use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)?

Comment: @Jerodev Because I'll probably need same logic for multiple models and I taught this was the better way since if I use mutators, I would have multiple same mutators in different models and like this I define the function only once

Comment: @N69S using `insteadof` wouldn't really solve my problem as it would allow me to use only one function (from the `trait` I choose), but I actually need to use both of them, and I need to use them implicitly, when I am retrieving data from table it should know which `getAttribute` should be triggered 1st and which should be triggered 2nd.

Comment: @niksrb yes it would, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a not recommended solution

```
//Traits

trait Maskable {

public function getAttribute($key) {
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    if(isset($this->maskable) && in_array($key, $this->maskable) && !empty($value)) {
        try {
            $value = 'x'.substr($value, -4);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}

trait Encryptable {

public function getAttribute($key) {
    if (in_array(Maskable::class, class_uses(self::class))) {
        $value = self::getMaskedAttribute($key);
    } else {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    }

    if(isset($this->encryptable) && in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && !empty($value)) {
        try {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

And then resolve the conflict

```
//My example model

class RentalApplication extends Model {
use Encryptable, Maskable {
    Encryptable::getAttribute insteadof Maskable;
    Maskable::getAttribute as getMaskedAttribute;
};

protected $encryptable = ['card_number'];
protected $maskable = ['card_number'];
}
```

Comment: Will try it, but why 'Not recommended' solution?

Comment: depends on the resolve conflict to be correct on every model using both traits for it to compile. i would recommend you to create another trait `EncryptableAndMaskable` wich uses `Maskable` and `Encryptable` and resolves the conflict (all logic in one place)

Comment: Got it. Your answer does not solves my specific problem is it goes to get value from `Maskable trait` before it is `decrypted` and then it's not the right value, but it gives me instructions how could I solve it, so I am going to pick it. Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @niksrb You're welcome, you provided only the `Crypt` code, so i worked on that